# Error Number: 1054, Expression Engine 2.7.3

Tags: error

This happens after I submit a channel form:

```
Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'field_id_0' in 'field list'
SELECT `field_id_0` FROM (`exp_channel_data`) WHERE `channel_id` = '0'
Filename: fieldtypes/select/ft.select.php
Line Number: 156
```

I did not make any updates, just changed some fields.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that one of the channel fields was at fault.

1. To narrow it down, I removed field by field from the template
2. After the error disappeared, I deleted the channel field and recreated it with the same settings.
3. Now just revert all changes to the template and you're good to go.

The error has since disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in a checkbox field, neither "Populate the menu manually" or "Populate the menu from another channel field" has been selected. Choose any of them and the error will be gone :D